# Informatica using URI based REST API

Tags: api, jira, informatica

I'm having real trouble getting Informatica PowerCenter or Developer to call a URI based REST API and I'm doing it for something simple (JIRA's API). Basically I want to call JIRA's worklog REST API which is a different URL for a list of issue ids and write it to our DB.

https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/6.2/

*/rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}/worklog*

- Informatica PowerCenter supports only HTTP transformation which is only a simple GET. Unfortunately the latest version is still stuck in the 'old' query type URL building where they append inputs into search strings. E.g. if I have a "key" input field with value "ABC-1" and the URL is jira/rest/api/2/search it would actually build the URL on the fly into jira/rest/api/2/search?key=ABC-1. While some of JIRA's API works this way, some use the URI way e.g. jira/rest/api/2/ABC-1/worklog which requires embedding the value into the URI. There's no way I can get this to work :-

  - if I do jira/rest/api/$key/worklog it still converts the URI into jira/rest/api/$key/worklog/?key=ABC-1 so $key does not get replaced
  - even if i pre-build the URI outside the mapping it's not feasible as the URI needs to be dynamic to the list of JIRA keys and anyway because it appends ? at the end JIRA throws an error (because ? is a reserved key word for this API)
  - HTTP transformation does not support NTLMv2 authentication which our company's JIRA instance may upgrade to shortly
  - Last resort is to use a Java transformation in which Informatica has quite little value add. This also means I need to somehow pass in the JIRA user password for authentication which is a separate challenge (versus just storing as a HTTP connection)
- Informatica Developer supports REST Web Consumer Transformation but has similar limitations with only building query type URL. Even worse I can't even dynamically build the URL since it's fixed to the HTTP connection object URL.

Am I straight outta luck?

Answer (score 0):

I got the query and here I would like to answer about this. I can write here only points and it might be you won’t be able to understand that thing properly. So Here I am putting link of blog where the task "how to [informatica read rest api](https://zappysys.com/blog/read-json-informatica-import-rest-api-json-file/) is mentioned in detail step by step with video tutotial. Some examples are also there. Feel free to visit

https://zappysys.com/blog/read-json-informatica-import-rest-api-json-file/

Hope it will help.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.